# Change Textarea field to multi Checkbox options

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i want to know how to change a textarea field in one of my theme files to multi checkbox options, this is the textarea code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="desc" class="head_bol"><?php _e("Tour description",ST_TEXTDOMAIN) ?> <span class="text-small text-danger">*</span>:</label>
    <textarea id="desc" name="st_desc" class="form-control"><?php echo stripslashes(STInput::request("st_desc",$excerpt)) ?></textarea>
    <div class="st_msg"><?php echo STUser_f::get_msg_html($validator->error('st_desc'),'danger') ?></div>
</div>
```

why i need checkbox instead of textarea : i want to let my vistors choose what's included in the tour . so there will be a lot of options to choose from.

this is the full php file link : https://ufile.io/sw95a

the code that i need to edit from line 69 to line 73 in the file

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: This "changing" operation depends on how you structured your whole page(s) code. So, you should provide more code and explanations.

Comment: Thank you for you reply Dakis , i have edited my question and this is the link for the full php file :https://ufile.io/sw95a 
please help me out

Comment: Now we have the code. But you need to explain to us - in terms of application logic - what you want to happen exactly, and on which event (on a button click, on a select in a combobox, on a text changed event in the control xyz, after the form pqr is submitted, etc). Please note that you can not change a textarea with other html control. You can just replace it.

Comment: Yes sir , i just want to replace it with multi checkbox options , so the user will have to choose from those options and they will printed on the tour info page what he choose from this checkbox options , and this options are : What's included in the Tour , Example : Tour Guide,Meals,English Speaking Guide, Hotel room , Wifi ...etc
i hope you understand what i mean and i really want to thank you for your help mr Dakis .

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But how do you want to replace it? You want to click on button and in that moment the textarea to disappear and a checkboxes group to appear? Or in other way?

Comment: No , I want the checkbox group to appear from the first time only and the user can't see OR use text box , so i want to replace text box with multi chckboxes group .

Comment: if you help me at this i will be so greatfull for you if you want me to pay for this i'm ready but please help me mr Dakis :)

Comment: I will certainly not accept, nor take any payment for some advices :-) Now, what is the problem exactly? Can you not write the code for a checkbox group in that page by yourself, per hand, and simply delete the code for the textarea?

Comment: No, Because my Website is a a tour Affiliate website , so users can register and add their tours and i get a comission on every booking , so the file that i send you file.php, is the file for the ADD TOUR page that users use to submit their tours , i use this theme : https://themeforest.net/item/traveler-traveltourbooking-wordpress-theme/10822683

Comment: this is an  image from the ADD TOUR page that will explain to you more : https://imgur.com/a/n77kS

Comment: when i delete the textarea code from the file i can't add the tour because he is required even when i delet the code i can't add the tour that's why i need to change it to checkbox , also if i add checkbox group and the user choose from them , the final result will not be printed in the tour page info , i hope you understand what i mean mr dakis

Comment: If you need to display a checkbox group to the user, then you MUST write its code in the add-tour file. You can simply let the textarea in the code, but make it invisible with: `<textarea style="display: none;" ...>`. This way, the textarea still remains active for the add tour operation, but not editable by the user. Further, if you add a checkbox group, you also MUST write code to read the options that a user have chosen, to save them, to display them and to print them.

Comment: It seems to me that this task is way too broad to be accomplshed with just a simple replace textarea operation.

Comment: how i can do this ? "MUST write code to read the options that a user have chosen, to save them, to display them and to print them" ?

Comment: Well that's the problem: there is too much to do. Your really best choice is to call to the company from where you bought the template and to ask them to implement this functionality for you. Even if it looks as a simple task, it is definitely not.

Comment: What you think about this plugin : Advanced Custom Fields , for wordpress i think he can help me at this , what you think ?

Comment: I am not a WP developer, but, in my opinion, it's a great plugin. I would not hesitate to use it. Plus, it's a 5 stars library. It is a plugin used by the theme developers. So, if you could implement it in your theme, it would be a good situation. Unfortunately I don't see, how I could help you further, even if I would want to. Try it and see how it can help you ;-) Don't forget that you must be able to process the resulting values from it, so, that you can read them, save them in your db, and print them to the user at any time. Anyway, I wish you best luck.

Comment: Thank you very much dakis , for your advices , i hope all the best for you man :)

Comment: You are very welcome! Any time. Have fun ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function radioClick() {
 if (document.getElementById('rb').checked == true) {
   document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
  document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#other{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Trip length:<br/>
<input type="radio" name="length" value="1 week" onClick="radioClick()"> 1 week<br>
<input type="radio" name="length" value="2 weeks" onClick="radioClick()"> 2 weeks<br>
<input type="radio" name="length" onClick="radioClick()" id="rb">Other
<br/>
<textarea name="length" id="other" value=""></textarea>
```

Comment: May I ask, why a textarea in a form is a bad practice? I am a bit surprised to read this, but I suppose you have a case in mind, which is a legit one for you. Could you please tell us a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Yes i want to change the input type from textarea to multi checkbox options , but where i have to enter this codes you give me , thank you so much

Comment: @dakis sorry, I wrote that there without really thinking. I usually have a lot of trouble receiving and processing textareas. so yeah, they''re not a bad practive (dumb me!) I just am not a fan of them. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So you're talking about DOM. Are you trying to make something where once someone fills out a page, it will save the data and replace the form questions with more questions? DOM is pretty easy, but what are you attempting to do?

Comment: I think I know what you want: you will have some check boxes, and if you click a certain one, it will make a textarea appear. when you uncheck it, the textarea dissapears. I can give you the code that you need for this, I just want to make sure this is the thing you want.

Comment: @SwiftShard I see. IMHO, the advices given based on one's own experience and perspective are very pertinent and helpful. And you actually did just that. Thanks for the explanation. Good luck.